# How to make mocha test fail on puppeteer pageerror

Tags: mocha.js, puppeteer

I am using mocha and puppeteer to test a page. I would like the test to fail if the page throws an uncaught exception.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
it('should fail because page has an error', async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  page.on('pageerror', (e) => {
    // TODO: Make the test fail somehow
    throw e;
  });

  await page.goto('http://example.com/page-that-throws-an-error');
});
```

When I run `mocha`, this test succeeds but leaves an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in my terminal.

I don't think I can use a `done(error)` callback because I am already using an async function and mocha will complain with `Error: Resolution method is overspecified`.

Answer (score 4):

I realized I can keep track of the errors the page throws, then check at the end of the test if the page threw any errors.

```js
it('should fail because page has an error', async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const pageErrors = [];
  page.on('pageerror', (e) => {
    pageErrors.push(e);
  });

  await page.goto('http://example.com/page-that-throws-an-error');

  for (const e of pageErrors) {
    throw e;
  }
});
```

This works, but the test only fails at the end when it checks that there are no errors. Ideally I would like to find a way for the test to fail as soon as the page throws an error.

Comment: It makes more sense to have `pageErrors` outside of `it()`, because then you can use it in other `it()` too. For example when you have a test which clicks something you'd also want to run the `for` loop which you defined there after clicking something via `puppeteer`. I found no way to remote the listener function of `page.on`...